# Switching between two different scenes Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make a scene transition in three.js and ran into a problem that the renderer won't transition to the new scene when requested. I have an Intro scene which contains a basic animation and after it finishes it should bring the user to the main scene.

```
var reqF;  

init();
intro_animation(); 
//animate();
init(){
   //initialize scenes, renderer, and cameras here

}

function intro_animation(){
   //intro animation code
   if( /*done*/ ){
      console.log("Exiting Intro Animation");
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(reqF);
      animate();
   }
   else{
      console.log("continuing intro animation");
      reqF = requestAnimationFrame(intro_animation);
      renderer.clear();
      renderer.render( backgroundScene, backgroundCamera );
      renderer.render(intro_scene,intro_cam);
   }

} 

function animate() {
   console.log("entering main animation");
   //main animation code
   reqF = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   renderer.clear();
   renderer.render( backgroundScene, backgroundCamera );
   renderer.render(scene,camera);

}
```

Edit1: So I added the cancelAnimationFrame() function but it is still looping when I open dev console and won't switch over to the main loop. Also the second renderer call inside the animation function renderers the background. I tried making a sequential call to animate() after the intro_animation() call but then I am unable to see the intro animation, so I commented it out.

Comment: ? you are rendering twice in your animate function. Also, you are calling `requestAnimationFrame` on both functions, but never cancelling either one. Voting to close, simple logic problem.

Comment: I am sorry I am a novice in Three.js but what do you mean by cancelling the requestAnimationFrame ? isn't that necessary for the animation loops.

Comment: To expand on what @2pha said, see the documentation for [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and [`cancelAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame). You need to terminate the first loop before you start the second.

Comment: ok I called cancelAnimationFrame inside the intro animation when it was done, but for some reason it still wont terminate and switch to the next loop as shown in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to solve it.

```
init();
animate();
intro_animation();
```

Calling animate before intro_animation somehow makes this work. I also added cancelAnimationFrame() to the intro_animation with a return call which prevents it from looping again.

```
function intro_animation(){
//intro animation code
   if( /*done*/ ){
         console.log("transitioning");
         window.cancelAnimationFrame(reqF);
         return;
   }
   else{
     console.log("continuing intro animation");
     reqF = requestAnimationFrame(intro_animation);
     renderer.clear();
     renderer.render( backgroundScene, backgroundCamera );
     renderer.render(intro_scene,intro_cam);
   }

}
```